# Jquery: Enable one form field and disable other when checkbox is clicked

Tags: jquery

I am looking for a better solution to achieve the subject.

- When a checkbox is clicked, disable select box and enable input field and vise versa.
  my code is

  ```
     <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      <select class="form-control recipe_cats otherrecipe_cat" id="recipe_cats" name="recipe_cats">
      <option value="-1">Books Category</option>
      <option value="30" class="level-0">Book1</option>
      <option value="48" class="level-0">Book2</option>
      <option value="49" class="level-0">Book3</option>
      </select>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3">
      <label class="control-label checkbox-inline" for="lblothercats">Not Listed</label> <sup><i class="fa fa-asterisk"></i></sup>
      <input class="form-control" type="checkbox" name="lblothercats" id="lblothercats" value="option1">
      <span class="help-block"></span>
      </div> <!-- /.form-group -->


      <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      <label class="control-label" for="otherrecipe_cat">Other Category</label> <sup><i class="fa fa-asterisk"></i></sup>
      <input type="text" class="form-control otherrecipe_cat" name="otherrecipe_cat" id="otherrecipe_cat" value="" role="input" aria-required="true" disabled="disabled" />
      <span class="help-block"></span>
      </div><!-- /.form-group -->
  ```

and my current code is

```
$('#lblothercats').change(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('input.otherrecipe_cat').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('select.recipe_cats').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        $('select.recipe_cats').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('input.otherrecipe_cat').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
}).trigger('change');
```

This works fine, but I am wondering if there is any better option or solution to achieve this? I will be writing many segments like this.

Regards

Comment: What do you mean by many segments? Can you share your whole html too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This works fine, but I am wondering if there is any better option or solution to achieve this?*

You can improve like:

```
$('#lblothercats').change(function () {
    $('select.recipe_cats').prop('disabled', this.checked);
    $('input.otherrecipe_cat').prop('disabled', !this.checked);
}).trigger('change');
```

You should use [**.prop()**](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [**.attr()**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), Go through [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)